# simple (tan like shape) function needed

Tags: functions, simulation

I need a function which initially falls slowly, then quickly and then slowly again.

Shape should be like tan but I want to be able to control the gradient

Properties needed:

$x = 0, y=0$

As $x$ increases $y$ decreases

As $x \rightarrow \infty$, $y \rightarrow -1$

(No definition for negative $x$ needed)

Comment: Did you try searching before asking? Even the Wikipedia has a [page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sigmoid_function) about similar functions, you would need to do just a small modification.

Comment: Thanks for pointing to that page . my math skills are non-existent. I know I would need to tweak that sigmoid function, but I have no other option but trial and error :/

Comment: Your description does not match tan. Perhaps you need to post a picture.

Comment: @Maesumi Perhaps a generic S shape curve is a better description. See the sigmoid function link posted by dtldarek

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[$$y = e^{-ax}-1$$](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=y+%3D+e%5E%28-x%29-1+from+0+to+5)
[$$y = \dfrac{1+e^{-ab}}{1+e^{a(x-b)}}-1$$](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=y+%3D%281%2Be%5E%28-2%2a5%29%29%2F%281%2Be%5E%282%2a%28x-5%29%29%29-1+from+0+to+10)
should do the job. You can play with the factor $a$ to control the gradient.

Comment: @RahulNarain Thanks. Updated.

Comment: Thanks, the 2nd one works nicely

Answer (score 0):

You can build on sample formulas on the wiki page you mentioned. For example $y=-kx/\sqrt{1+(kx)^2}$ for different values of $k$.